Trouble understanding Haskell function
I'm having trouble understanding why the following code correctly compiles:
f :: a -> Maybe a
f = return Just 3

return Just has a type of Monad m => m (a -> Maybe a) so I'm not sure why passing in an Int unwraps the monad.
You can even get a little crazy with it:
f :: a -> Maybe a
f = return Just (Just . Just . Just . Just)

Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

You're using return from the reader monad (->) Int, which is defined as const. In this case return Just has type Int -> a -> Maybe a.
f = return Just 3
  = const Just 3
  = Just


This is somewhat confusing because you probably have only seen type class instances for data/newtype types, but they can be defined over any Haskell type, so here's what's happening here:
There's no "unwrapping" happening here. There simply is a monad instance for (->) r which you might know as Reader.
You can check that this exists by typing :i (->) in ghci:
ghci> :i (->)
-- some stuff which isn't relevant here, and then:
instance Applicative ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’

Instantiating this for our case:
return :: a -> ((->) r) a -- which is just a -> r -> a
-- 
Just :: x -> Maybe x
-- ==>
return Just :: r -> (x -> Maybe x) -- after substituting a = x -> Maybe x
-- ==>
return Just 3 :: x -> Maybe x -- after substituting r = Int

so return Just 3 just becomes a fancy way to write Just. Since we're not using r you can pass whatever you like for it, even undefined.


return Just has a type of Monad m => m (a -> Maybe a)

Correct, and applying something to it, e.g., return Just 3 – which is equivalent to (return Just) 3 – implies that return Just must be a function and therefore its type, m (a -> Maybe a), must correspond to a function type. So, the Monad instance for (->) r is used.
The TypeApplications extension can help to understand what's happening here:
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> :type return @((->) _)
return @((->) _) :: a -> w -> a

Essentially, the particular type of return for the Monad instance you are using is:
return :: a -> w -> a

When passing Just to return as in return Just – since you are applying the function – the first parameter of the return type goes away, and its type is inferred to be a -> Maybe a because that is the type of Just:
ghci> :type return @((->) _) Just
return @((->) _) Just :: w -> (a -> Maybe a)

So, the particular type of return Just for the monad of functions is:
return Just :: w -> (a -> Maybe a)

Finally, passing 3 results in return Just 3 :: a -> Maybe a.

You can also ask for the type of the return within the whole expression, with my handy Forall What? trick: let { it :: forall what. _; it = (return :: what) Just 3 } in it will tell you that this instance of return has the type (a -> Maybe a) -> Integer -> a -> Maybe a, where the Integer comes from defaulting.


so I'm not sure why passing in an Int unwraps the monad.

You perform function application, so the only Monad instance that is fit, is instance Monad (->) a [Haskell-src]:

-- | @since 2.01
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)

-- | @since 2.01
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
    liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)

-- | @since 2.01
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r


Thus thus means that return uses the pure function, and pure is implemented as const.
So the m in Monad m => m (a -> Maybe a) will be (->) b, and thus boil down to b -> (a -> Maybe a). The implementation of return is then const, so:
f = return Just 3
  = const Just 3
  = (\x -> Just) 3
  = Just

It thus essentially ignores the parameter, and returns the function wrapped in the monad.
